# React: Component randomly doesn't refresh after state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, render, crud

I am working on a CRUD (express, mongoose, mongodb) which is mostly working as expected... except when it comes to rendering the entries after deleting X amount of them.
[Not deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CayR6.gif)

Sometimes I can delete 10 entries without any issues, until the component is empty, and other times I delete some entries and then the page just stop rending the updated data and enters an infinite loading state in the browser; only when I hard reload the browser the page renders the latest data, yet it does delete the entry , it just freezes it seems!

```
From React:
useEffect(() => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries(["allUsers"]);
  });

const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (userid) => {
      return await axios.delete("/api/deleteuser", { data: { userid: userid } });
    },
  });

 const handleDelete = (userid) => {
    mutation.mutate(userid);
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  };
```

```
From Mongoose
const deleteUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await newUser.findOneAndDelete({ userid: req.body.userid });
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

Tried invalidating the query cache at the delete function but the result is the same. It just happens randomly, as if the request was not fulfilled... in dev tools/network the request is never fulfilled but the data, whenever it does work, is updated.[Network/pending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSZOP.gif)

Edit: I'm using a mongoDB free account... I've read sometimes the response times are not the best, perhaps it is the reason?

Comment: That `return docs` isn't going to do anything for one...

Comment: True, the mongoose docs had it (findoneanddelete) so I added it in case it would fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. `useEffect` without a dependency array is pretty pointless. It will run every time the component is rerendered.
2. I assume you are using react-query. Try moving your `queryClient.invalidate` to `onSuccess` or `onSettled` in your `useMutation` config object. This will ensure your query is invalidated only after the mutation is done.
   https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/mutations#mutation-side-effects

Comment: Tried your suggestion, with both onSuccess and onSettled, same outcome after a couple requests the component doesn't update the deleted entries!